# How to know a URL is existing using Selenium WebDriver using C#?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In my application I store a list of URLs and only products that have an existing URL (ie not any 404 or Page not found or broken URL).

I want to view in my pages, then to navigate to that page. Now I need to get code that checks if the given URL is existing using WebDriver in selenium and C#.

Comment: Why not use WebClient.DownloadString(url) to do this? There is no need to involve selenium which is unefficeint.

Comment: how can I use it? How I know a page is exist or not? using this code.

Comment: If the page you are requesting does not exist (404), the method will throw a WebException, see MSDN here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadstring

Comment: try{ new WebClient().DownloadString(url); } catch (WebException ex) { ... }

Comment: In fact the WebException is thrown by WebRequest object which is underlying inside WebClient class, so you can use WebRequest class directly too. You can google for how to use this class.

Answer (score 0):

```
string urlFraction = "/myfolder/some.html";
double seconds = 10;
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds));
bool wellTheAddressBarChanged = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.UrlContains(urlFraction));

// TODO: Give IE11 special treatment here.
bool thePageActuallyLoaded = wait.Until(d => ((IJavaScriptExecutor)d).ExecuteScript("return document.readyState").Equals("complete"));
```